# What exactly happens to your Relationship NPCs after a conflict?

Tags: trollbabe

On page 61 there is some sort of table that explains what happens to the Relationship-NPCs that you ticked off for a reroll during a conflict. It looks more or less like this:

```
+--------------------------+---------------+-------------+
|                          | Goal succeeds | Goal fails  |
+--------------------------+---------------+-------------+
| Trollbabe Inconvenienced | NPC Injured   | ?           |
| Trollbabe Injured        | NPC Fine      | NPC Killed  |
| Trollbabe Incapacitated  | ?             | NPC Injured |
+--------------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

*Note: it looks nothing like this, but contains the same information. the question marks are there for cases not covered by the original diagram.*

However, right after that, it goes on to describe the two possible outcomes for a first reroll in a described scenario.

It says:

> [If the Trollbabe succeeds, she] is not seized by her enemies and [the NPC] is fine [...]

However, you only get the opportunity to make a reroll, if you fail the first roll (this is even mentioned in the described scenario.) This means the Trollbabe must have been inconvenienced. So if you then succeed in the first reroll and achieve your goal, the NPC should be injured according to the diagram.

It then describes the consequences of failing the reroll:

> [The Trollbabe] has been seized by her enemies and [the NPC] is injured.

This again doesn't make any sense, because a failed first reroll means an injury to the Trollbabe which, in case of a failed Goal, would mean the NPC's death.

Can anybody explain to me, what I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: What version of trollbabe are you playing?  I don't see any sort of table for this in the pdf, just text.

Answer (score 2):

The rulebook I have states, contrary to your text, that:

> Relationships can be damaging to the people
>   involved. If a re-roll based on a relationship fails,
>   no matter how the whole series turns out, the
>   person in question will wind up at one “consequence"
>   level worse than the trollbabe does, if he
>   or she is physically present during the conflict.

So if the re-roll based on the relationship succeeds the relation is presumably fine.  If not they are still fine if they weren't physically present.  If they were physically present and the roll failed they would then be injured at the end of the conflict, or worse if additional re-rolls are failed. To be clear:

Normal rolls  (the relationship roll in our example is made here.  You can use relationship rolls as a free extra consequence free roll in a series but then it doesn't regen till later, like an item): Success means no problems, failure means discommodation if the trollbabe is successful without rerolls.

1st reroll: Success means injury, failure means incapacitation

2nd reroll: Success means incapacitation, failure means death or GM-described death-equivalent chew-toy fate

3rd reroll: Success means death or GM-described death-equivalent chew-toy fate, failure means an undescribed fate worse than death (by one consequence level).